# Custom Dir for Prerender html files of Vue SPA

Tags: vue.js, single-page-application, prerender

Guess my turn to ask regarding [prerender-spa-plugin](https://github.com/chrisvfritz/prerender-spa-plugin) in Vue App.

I wanted to assigned rendered routed page HTMLs from `/dist` folder into subfolders such as following format:

```
/dist/
 - index.html
 - /pages/
     - about.html
     - contact.html
```

As now, my `about.html` and `contact.html` are rendered at `dist` instead, together with `index.html`

My SPA prerender snippet for `vue.config.js` as below

```
pluginOptions: {
    prerenderSpa: {
      registry: undefined,
      renderRoutes: [
        '/',
        '/about'
        '/contact',
      ],
      useRenderEvent: true,
      headless: true,
      onlyProduction: true,
    },
```

So how i can achieve my rendering as format above? I kinda figure `renderedRoute` is something i need to deal with. Thank you in advance (_ _ ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible, but you change somethings.

First you need to change your routes in VueRouter. You must to declare your routes the follow way:

```js
// ./src/router/index.js
import Vue from 'vue';
import VueRouter from 'vue-router';
import Home from '@/views/Home.vue';
import About from '@/views/About.vue';
import Contact from '@/views/Contact.vue';

Vue.use(VueRouter);

// IMPORANT HERE
const routes = [
  { path: '/', name: 'Home', component: Home },
  { path: '/pages/contact.html', name: 'contact', component: Contact },
  { path: '/pages/about.html', name: 'About', component: About },
];

const router = new VueRouter({
  mode: 'history',
  base: process.env.BASE_URL,
  routes,
});

export default router;
```

See that your routes must be declared with ".html" in your path.

Second you must to change your "vue.config.js":

```js
//vue.config.js
const path = require('path');
const PrerenderSPAPlugin = require('prerender-spa-plugin');

module.exports = {
  configureWebpack: {
    plugins: [
      new PrerenderSPAPlugin({
        staticDir: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),

        // IMPORTANT HERE
        routes: ['/', '/pages/about.html', '/pages/contact.html'],

        // IMPORTANT HERE
        postProcess(renderedRoute) {
          renderedRoute.route = renderedRoute.originalRoute;
          renderedRoute.html = renderedRoute.html.split(/>[\s]+</gim).join('><');
          if (renderedRoute.route.endsWith('.html')) {
            renderedRoute.outputPath = path.join(__dirname, 'dist', renderedRoute.route);
          }
          return renderedRoute;
        },
      }),
    ],
  },
};
```

Again your routes must be declared with ".html" and you must apply custom `postProcess` method.

Ready.

Comment: Read thoroughly, so if I still need to keep my app route `/contact` and `/about` but the files allocated according my desired format in `/dist` folder, i just need to ignore tweaking `router/index.js` correct? As i just need to add configureWebpack with `postProcess(renderedRoute)`. Thanks for replying !

Comment: The routes in VueRouter and the routes in PrerenderSPAPlugin must be equal. In this case, you must create 4 routes: `/contact`, `/about`, `/pages/contact.html`, `/pages/about.html`.

Comment: The routes `/contact` and `/pages/contact.html` use the same component. And the routes `/about` and `/pages/about.html` use the same component. Do you can understand?

Comment: Yeap got it. I will adjust according my page structures. Found both `configureWebpack` and `pluginOptions` behave differently. Thanks again

Comment: You are welcome. Please accept this answer and this will help others people, thanks. [How to accept an answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)